# Python logging.Formatter uses "%"-formatting instead of "{" even when "{" specified

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, formatting

I tried to create a custom logger with a custom formatter, inheriting them from `logging.Logger` and `logging.Formatter` accordingly. However, even though I specified `style` to be `"{"`, I get an error. As far as I understood, this error is caused by the fact, that formatter tries to format using old-style `%` formatting.

Here's example of my `logger.py`, `formatter.py` and `main.py` to reproduce this.

```py
# logger.py
import logging

from formatter import CustomFormatter

class CustomLogger(logging.Logger):
    def __init__(self, name: 'str'):
        super().__init__(name)
        self._console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()

        format_string_for_console = '[{levelname}] {name}: {message}'
        time_format_string = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%Z'

        console_formatter = CustomFormatter(
            fmt=format_string_for_console,
            datefmt=time_format_string,
            style='{')

        self._console_handler.setFormatter(console_formatter)
```

```py
# formatter.py
import copy
import logging

class CustomFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def __init__(self, fmt: 'str' = None, datefmt: 'str' = None, style: 'str' = '%'):
        self.__format = f'Some modification to default format {fmt}'
        self.__date_format = datefmt
        self.__style = style
        super().__init__(fmt, datefmt, style)

    def format(self, record: 'logging.LogRecord') -> str:
        record_copy = copy.copy(record)
        return logging.Formatter(
            fmt=self.__format,
            datefmt=self.__date_format,
            style=self.__style
        ).format(record_copy)
```

```py
# main.py
from logger import CustomLogger as CL

logger = CL('test_logger')
logger.warning('info_msg {}', 1)
```

Don't tell me about ridiculousness of this MVP, it's extremely minified to be as little as possible, but still reproduce an error. The error I get with this has this stacktrace:

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1085, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 929, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 668, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 373, in getMessage
    msg = msg % self.args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
Call stack:
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Message: 'info_msg {}'
Arguments: (1,)
```

I must be doing something wrong, but I can't get what. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it a typo ? Shouldn't it be an f-string: `format_string_for_console = f'[{levelname}] {name}: {message}'` ?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer, definitely not. Everything is done according to the docs. Usage of `{` means that this string must be formated using `.format()` method. As you probably know, this method supports kwargs. `levelname`, `name` and `message` are not known in `__init__`, but they will be inserted later by `logging` library automatically, when it will format the string with `.format()`  method. The problem here is that, however `format_string_for_console` is formatted correctly (with `.format`), arguments passed to `logger.warning` are not (they try to use `%`-style formatting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two levels of formatting:

1. Formatting the message and arguments passed in a logging call. These are *always* formatted using `%`, for backward compatibility - logging predates the other kinds of formatting.
2. Formatting the message generated by the previous step together with other things such as the time of the event, process ID, thread ID, current function, current module and any other contextual information passed to the logging call. This level can use the `style` passed to a formatter to decide how to format the message. In this higher level of formatting, the `message`  in the format string of the formatter will hold the value determined in the previous step.

Comment: Ok, so, do I understand correctly, that there's no way to make arguments passed to `logger.warning` (or any other log-level) to be formated via `'{}'.format()`? If so, it looks weird. I understand backward compat issues, but weird anyways

Comment: That's right. It's not especially weird, as it was the only thing going at the time for formatting. Since then we've had `string.Template`, `{}`-formatting and f-strings. It can't be changed now because of the large body of existing code that uses %-formatting.